# zsh variable substitution modifies surrounding string

Tags: shell, zsh

Why does the "c" character go missing in the following example?

```sh
var="\bINSERT"
echo abc${var}def
> abINSERTdef
```

Is there any documentation that tells me how to do similar things or disable the behaviour?

I can't find any shell variables documentation.

Comment: `echo` is allowed to interpret escape sequences however it likes. It's allowed, f/e, to treat `\b` as a backspace, so it deletes the character before it. (Bash only does this when `-e` is given as an argument, but honoring `-e` is itself a way that bash breaks [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); this is one of the few places where default behavior of zsh is more standards-compliant than that of bash)

Comment: If you want reliable behavior that _doesn't_ include this, use `printf` instead of `echo`. Specifically: `printf '%s\n' "$var"`, or `printf '%s\n' "abc${var}def"`

Comment: To be clear, the variable substitution isn't modifying the string at all. `echo` is interpolating escapes during the output process.

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [unix.se] has an extensive writeup in an answer by Stephane Chazelas that I fully endorse.

Comment: (If you want reliable/portable behavior that _does_ include this, the best choice is still not echo: `printf '%b\n' "abc${var}def"` will transform `\b` to a backspace even in bash, sh, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : You refer to bash, but the OP uses zsh. From my understanding of the zsh man page, zsh has the same design flaw however.

Comment: @user1934428, I was speaking to POSIX, not to bash _or_ zsh. Granted, zsh isn't a POSIX-compliant shell, but it is _informed_ by the standard, and I was careful to set out in my comments what does and doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command substitution isn't doing anything wrong -- it's `echo` whose behavior is surprising (legally; POSIX allows, but does not require, `echo` to interpret backslash escape sequences by default, so zsh is not in the wrong here).

```
printf '%s\n' abc${var}def
```

...doesn't have your problem (but for portability to non-zsh shells, I would quote `"abc${var}def"`).

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and the POSIX spec for `echo` at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

As already was mentioned in the comments, the zsh implementation of the internal `echo` differs from the one implemented by the external `echo` command.

If you want to continue using `echo`, there are several workarounds:

1. Do a `echo -E ...`; the `-E` turns off the backslash interpretation.
2. Do a `command echo ...`; the keyword *command* forces the shell to use the external *echo* command.
3. Set in the shell the option `set bsd_echo` and then just leave the `echo` command as it is. The option tells the shell to not use by default the backslash interpretation for its internal *echo* command.

Comment: The `-E` argument isn't available in any POSIX-compliant `echo` implementation (the standard explicitly disallows anything other than `-n` or a string with a backslash from having any nonliteral meaning); I do not recommend using it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : It does not need to. The OP tagged the question with _zsh_, so a plain `echo` would invoke the internal command of zsh, and this offers `-E`.